# SQL JOIN QUERY INSERT INTO(PHPMYADMIN)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query insert into that i'm using 2 tables

1st table is applicant_notif which has
notif_id 
email
notif_fk_table
notif_content

2nd table is users which has 
user_id
email
password

I am using even scheduler to auto query some notifications then it will send to all account.

Now, my query in event scheduler is

```
INSERT INTO amilyar_applicant_notif (email, notif_fk_table, notif_content) VALUES ('would be the all emails in users table', 'amilyar_properties','Reminder: You need to pay for your...')
```

What would be the proper syntax that i will query in event scheduler to get all the emails in users table and send to applicant_notif table

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO amilyar_applicant_notif (email, notif_fk_table, notif_content) 
SELECT email, 'amilyar_properties','Reminder: You need to pay for your...' 
FROM users;
```

Comment: it wont add because its in diff table and no VALUES

Comment: You mean, this statement won't insert anything? Or do you mean that the results of the select are not what you want in the notif table?